# Comparing motors with different output rating but same voltage rating

Tags: motor, brushless-dc-motor

How will the rated speed of two dc motors(bldc) compare if they have different output power rating but have same input voltage rating?

Goal is to select a motor of appropriate rated output power which gives good rpm(speed is of importance) minimising discharge current from the battery source for the motor.

Comment: Do you have the Kv for the motors? This is the constant that relates voltage to RPM. This will allow you to estimate maximum speed based on the voltage you have available. For example, if the Kv is 50 rpm/volt, and you have a 20V supply, you should be able to get 50 * 20 = 1000 RPM with no load. Actually it will always be a bit less due to resistive loss. Probably you should update your question with a lot more information. What speed and power do you actually need? And links to data for both motors. And what is the DC voltage available for your motor driver?

Comment: Without knowing torque requirements there is no relationship between speed and power a very high speed motor may be very low power, while a high power motor can be designed for almost any speed.

Comment: @mkeith I'm not actually comparing two motors. So I don't have any specs sheet. I need a motor with a high rated speed but low rated current value(therefore I guessed  low rated output value ). So that the battery set  gives me a good run time. (I'm designing a drive train for a electric go kart). If you still think I should provide numbers then I 'll put some numbers with the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No conclusion can be drawn about motor speed based only on input power and voltage.

The mechanical output power of a motor is torque * speed.

If you use N-m for torque and rad/sec for speed, then the power will be in Watts, and there are no proportionality constants. You can just multiply N-m * rad/sec.

Also, the torque is proportional to the input current (see the torque constant, Kt), and the voltage is proportional to speed (see the voltage constant Kv). Because of the winding resistance, the applied voltage will have to be a bit higher than what you calculate using Kv.

The motor current is typically limited by heating. Current flowing in the copper windings gives rise to heat. Since current is proportional to torque, this means that torque is also limited. Since power is speed * torque, max motor power is proportional to speed. In other words, the max torque is constant, so the maximum available output power linearly ramps up from 0 to max power at the max power point.

So now this is the important part. A motor rated at 100 W of output power will not be able to produce 100 W of output power at any speed. It will produce 100 W only at its max speed. At lower speeds, power will be linearly reduced to zero at zero rpm. This is why you need to select a motor whose rated speed is somewhat matched to the speed you actually need. Power by itself is not enough to select a motor.

Anyway, if you know the speed and torque required for your application, that is a good starting point. It is very hard to select a motor if these are unknown.

Once you know the speed and torque, you can use Kv and Kt and winding resistance to roughly estimate the input power required to spin the motor at a given speed. You just need to make sure that your torque and speed are within the capabilities of the motor. Technically, you need one more thing to estimate power input, but I am going to ignore it.

I would not buy a BLDC that does not give you this information (at least Kv and winding resistance). Note, if the motor has a full torque and power vs RPM curve, but does not give Kv or Kt, that is OK, too. The point is, there has to be some engineering data available.

Comment: That was very helpful @mkeith thank you!  Tell me that one more thing required to estimate power input.

Comment: No load current.

Comment: http://www.radiocontrolinfo.com/brushless-motor-efficiency/#2

Comment: wow cool stuff. The page is really good. Now I know what is ground zero when it comes to selecting appropriate motor.

Answer (score 2):

You need to find the speed of each, either from data sheets or measurement.

The motors will have been designed for a particular speed, but speed and power will not necessarily change proportionally with each other.

There are motors designed for high rpm and low torque and vice versa. You need to find out what the characteristics are for the ones you have- or purchase new ones which have all the information supplied.